# Programa com expressões de booleana entra no bloco do if todas as vezes

Tags: python, python-3.x, booleano

```
    prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
    suffix = "ack"
    for letter in prefixes:
        if letter[0] == "Q"or"O":
            print(letter+"uack")
            continue
        print(letter+suffix)
```

Resposta esperada:

```
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Ouack
Pack
Quack
```

Resposta adquirida:

```
Juack
Kuack
Luack
Muack
Nuack
Ouack
Puack
Quack
```

Não entendi o porque de `or` quando usado retorna tudo como `True` ao em vez de selecionar as variáveis que eu digitei no código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `or` não funciona como imagina, o correto seria:

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
for letter in prefixes:
    if letter[0] == "Q" or letter[0] == "O":
        print(letter + "uack")
    else:
        print(letter + "ack")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/D80k2z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gojlekul-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Prefixes.py).

Você estava comparando a expressão `letter[0] == "Q"` que pode ser verdadeiro ou falso de acordo com o valor de `letter[0]`. Como tem um `or` a única forma da decisão ser tomada sem avaliar mais nada é quando esta expressão seja verdadeira, porque é certo que o bloco deve ser executado. E até aí está certo. O `or` também é o adequado aí. O problema está na segundo expressão do `or` que não retorna o que você espera.

Qual o resultado booleano de `"O"`? Por definição, todos os valores que não sejam considerados zerados ou vazios são falsos, todos os outros valores são verdadeiros, então `"O"` é verdadeiro. Então toda vez que a primeira expressão der falsa e ele vai tentar a segunda esta é sempre verdadeira, e portanto faz tudo ser verdadeiro.

O que de fato você queria fazer é `letter[0] == "O"` porque aí a expressão pode dar verdadeira no momento certo, mas dará falsa em grande parte dos casos.

As outras mudanças eu fiz porque é mais legível e óbvio

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer minha dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de fazer seria:

```
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
for prefix in prefixes:
    suffix = 'uack' if prefix in {'Q', 'O'} else 'ack'
    print(prefix + suffix)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BouncyGorgeousOpengroup) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MLRIB1) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/d2ec11f9185ec34915d1eb598032bcd8)</sup>

Basicamente substituindo as duas comparações com `==` pelo operador `in` e a verificação por uma condição *inline*, ou ternário, se preferir. Eu particularmente acho esta forma mais legível para humanos.

Comment: Nunca tinha visto antes o uso de operadores dentro de uma linha, valeu pela dica vou dar uma pesquisada nisso também.

Comment: Existe algum motivo especial (talvez performance) para usar `set` em vez de `lista`/`tuple` neste caso?

Comment: @Miguel sim, a busca em um set é O(1), enquanto nos outros é O(n), mas não necessariamente isso se reflete na execução, dado o tamanho do conjunto.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson , sim, é motivo suficiente.